# How to stop phone keyboard from pushing my UI upwards?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, user-interface

I'm trying to make a portfolio website with React. It's made of 4 sections each 100vh and I'm snap scrolling up and down. The bottom section is my "Contact me" form. It all works well but when I was testing on my phone I noticed that whenever I select the input field my keyboard pops up and instead of overlaying my app it just pushes it upwards and breaks the UI.

I'm uploading some images. Is there any way to make the keyboard just appear over the website instead of pushing all the content up?

[image: Normal UI]

[image: Broken UI]

This is the CSS for an individual section:

```
.snap-section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

And this is the css for the "root" element:

```
#root {
  background: radial-gradient(
    circle,
    rgba(1, 11, 56, 1) 0%,
    rgba(1, 20, 110, 1) 100%
  );
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I tried using "position: fixed" and "position: absolute" but that just makes the section on top currently visible.

Comment: How is the person supposed to see what they're typing if the keyboard covers up the input elements?

Comment: I didn't think of that actually. Well, is there a way to handle this whole situation better? Do you think I should just display the field that is being typed into when the keyboard pops up?